# Article title and first paragraph extraction in Imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have to extract some information from multiple news sites on a daily basis. Specifically, i have to extract a news article's:

1. Title
2. URL
3. First Paragraph

I have tried using Imacros. I have been successful in pulling out data from websites by modifying my code to suit that particular website's structure. I was wondering if a single code can cater to different site structures.

For instance, in [this article](http://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-britain-economy-boe-idUKKCN0US1NU20160114), the title can be accessed by

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=CLASS:article-headline EXTRACT TXT
```

However, for [this article](http://www.ansa.it/english/news/business/2016/01/14/cgil-chief-urges-stand-against-lay-offs_e2454bfa-9975-4204-abab-13252a92aba6.html), I have to modify this code to:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE H1 ATTR=CLASS:news-title EXTRACT TXT
```

Is there a code which can extract title from both of these website, or for that matter, any news website?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code that allows you extracting titles from two (and more) websites:

```
SET arr "[uk.reuters.com , CLASS:article-headline]"
ADD arr "[www.ansa.it , CLASS:news-title]"
' here you can add other sites like so:
' ADD arr "[someSite , attributesForTitle]"

SET sat EVAL("var arr = '{{arr}}'.split(']['); var sat = {}; for (i in arr) { var a = arr[i].replace(/[\\]\\[]/g, '').split(/\\s*,\\s*/); sat[a[0]] = a[1]; } JSON.stringify(sat);")
SET attr EVAL("var attr = ''; var sat = JSON.parse('{{sat}}'); for (i in sat) if ('{{!URLCURRENT}}'.indexOf(i) > -1) { var attr = sat[i]; break; } attr.trim();")

TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR={{attr}} EXTRACT=TXT
```

---

You might also like such a simple but not strict solution:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=CLASS:article-headline EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=CLASS:news-title EXTRACT=TXT
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 6

SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/#EANF#/g, '').replace(/\\[EXTRACT\\]/g, '');")
```